# Allowing pagebreaks for shaded theorems using thmtools

Tags: page-breaking, theorems, amsthm, thmtools

I just searched for a way of allowing pagebreaks when using shaded `theorem`-environments from `thmtools`. I found my question was, somewhat, answered [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/34407/6398) (the second solution) with a comment from the package's author Ulrich Schwarz. However, I'd like to keep defining `theorem`-like environments as follows

```
\declaretheorem[shaded={bgcolor=LightGrey},name=Definition,parent=chapter,
    % refname={definition,definitions},
    Refname={Definition,Definitions}]{Def}
```

i.e. without having to declare an extra (rather bulky) `theoremstyle` for each environment I define.
Is it possible to use the "`preheadhook`-`postfoothook`-trick" with `mdframed` globally, while retaining the overall interface and style I would get with my above `\declaretheorem`-example?

As I understand, shaded `theorem`-environments in `thmtools` are already implemented using `mdframed` anyway, so I thought it should be possible to allow pagebreaks by redefining some internal `thmtools` command, by setting some global option, or something along those lines.

I hope this is actually a valid question, as it was, more or less, already answered in 2011.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shaded theorems in `thmtools` are implemented with the `shadethm` package, not `mdframed`.

You can do the shading with `mdframed` instead by passing the option

```
mdframed={backgroundcolor=LightGrey}
```

to the theorem declaration.  This will allow page breaks in the defintion and gives output as in the sample below.

If the options you want to pass to `mdframed` are more complicated, you can set-up a style

```
\usepackage{mdframed}
\mdfdefinestyle{thmstyle}{backgroundcolorl=LightGrey,
   leftmargin=40pt,
   rightmargin=40pt}
```

and then pass

```
mdframed={style=thmstyle}
```

to the declaration instead of the `shaded` option.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\declaretheorem[mdframed={backgroundcolor=LightGrey},
  name=Definition,parent=chapter,
  Refname={Definition,Definitions}]{Def}

\begin{document}

\mbox{}
\vspace{14cm}
\begin{Def}
  Some long definition.
  Some long definition.
  Some long definition.
  Some long definition.
  Some long definition.
  Some long definition.
  Some long definition.
  Some long definition.
  Some long definition.
  Some long definition.
  Some long definition.
  Some long definition.
  Some long definition.
  Some long definition.
  Some long definition.
  Some long definition.
  Some long definition.
  Some long definition.
  Some long definition.
  Some long definition.
  Some long definition.
  Some long definition.
  Some long definition.
  Some long definition.
  Some long definition.
  Some long definition.
  Some long definition.
  Some long definition.
  Some long definition.
  Some long definition.
  Some long definition.
  Some long definition.
  Some long definition.
  Some long definition.
  Some long definition.
  Some long definition.
  Some long definition.
  Some long definition.
  Some long definition.
  Some long definition.
\end{Def}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Just note that it is a good idea to leave the breaking until when the document is almost done. `mdframed` may have some issues with theorem break that ends up looking odd (such as placing the box end on the next page, not sure if this is an issue when combined with `thmtools`). So for my own projects I now use unbreakble theorems and also provide theorems that are breakable and then manually change the environment. That seems to provide better results.