# Theorems spanning pages without losing width

Tags: page-breaking, amsmath, mdframed, shading, thmtools

I use `declaretheoremstyle` to declare a theorem environment. I like the format of `shaded`, it gives a special background color without shorten the width of a text. But one problem is that a theorem block does not span in 2 pages. So if a block is too long, it intersects with the bottom margin of the page:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}% just for the example
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage{mdframed}

\declaretheoremstyle[
spaceabove=6pt, spacebelow=6pt,
headfont=\normalfont\bfseries,
postheadspace=1em,
notefont=\bfseries,
notebraces={(}{)},
bodyfont=\itshape,
shaded={bgcolor=yellow!20}
]{thmstyle}

\declaretheorem[style=thmstyle,name=Theorem]{theorem}

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}[name]
...
\end{theorem}

\renewcommand{\listtheoremname}{List of Theorems}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\listtheoremname}
\listoftheorems[ignoreall,show=theorem]

\end{document}
```

I tried to follow this [proposition](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/34407/5110) by using `preheadhook` and `postfoothook`. It does solve the problem of spanning, but it shortens the width of a text, as I showed [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/247302/5110).

I think i will go with the authentic width (as `shaded` gives), does anyone know how to make it span in 2 pages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `mdframed` key to interact with the [`mdframed`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mdframed) package and set the margins to the appropriate values (the settings I used in the code below reproduce the original settings):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}% just for the example
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\declaretheoremstyle[
headfont=\normalfont\bfseries,
postheadspace=1em,
notefont=\bfseries,
notebraces={(}{)},
bodyfont=\itshape,
mdframed={
  hidealllines=true,
  skipabove=10pt,
  backgroundcolor=yellow!20,
  innerrightmargin=2pt,
  innerleftmargin=2pt,
  innertopmargin=0pt,
  innerbottommargin=0pt,
  leftmargin=-2pt,
  rightmargin=-2pt,
  }
]{thmstyle}

\declaretheorem[style=thmstyle,name=Theorem]{theorem}
\renewcommand{\listtheoremname}{List of Theorems}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[4]
\begin{theorem}[Some name]
\lipsum[4]
\end{theorem}
\lipsum[4]

\end{document}
```

The output:

[image]

Comment: That works, thank you... Actually, the reason why I use `declaretheoremstyle` is to put a background color. So I would like the other things to be exactly the same as the default theorem environment. So do you think `spacebelow`, `spaceabove` and `postheadspace` are all well set (i.e., why are they `6pt` or `1em`)? And what about `skipabove` and `skipbelow` of `mdframed`?

Comment: @SoftTimur You're welcome. `postheadspace` has no problem. The new set of settings (at the bottom of my answer) will give you the desired result.

Comment: I tried your new setting, I think it shorten a little bit the width, no? Whereas, `shaded` does not shorten the width, its background shading exceeds a little bit the width... Also, should `skipabove`, `skipbelow` of `mdframed` be set? Should `spacebelow` and `spaceabove` be `6pt`?

Comment: @SoftTimur No. The settings provided give a width equal to `\textwidth` for the text and the frame will protrude `2pt` on both sides. I've updated my answer providing settings that (according to my tests) reproduce the settings of the `shaded` style you originally had.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple solution with the `framed` option of `ntheorem`, which has tools for selectively typeset theorem lists:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}% just for the example
\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[thmmarks, thref, amsmath, framed]{ntheorem}
\usepackage{thmtools}

\usepackage{framed}
\colorlet{framecolor}{VioletRed4}
\theoremframepreskip{6pt}
\theoremframepostskip{6pt}
\theoreminframepreskip{4pt}
\theoreminframepostskip{4pt}
\theoremheaderfont{\upshape\bfseries}
\theorembodyfont{\itshape}
\theoremseparator{.}
\colorlet{shadecolor}{yellow!20}
\def\theoremframecommand{\colorbox{shadecolor}}
\newshadedtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}


\def\theoremframecommand{\setlength\fboxrule{1pt}\colorlet{shadecolor}{LavenderBlush2!60!}\fcolorbox{framecolor}{shadecolor}}
\theoremheaderfont{\scshape}
\theorembodyfont{\upshape}
\newshadedtheorem{defi}{Definition}

\theoremlisttype{allname}
\begin{document}
\vspace*{18cm}

Blahblahblah
\begin{theorem}[Named theorem]
  Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text.Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text.Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text.Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text.Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text.Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text.

  \lipsum[1]
\end{theorem}
Blah blah blah
\colorlet{shadecolor}{LavenderBlush2}
\begin{defi}
  $ \boldsymbol \pi $ is the ratio of the perimeter of a circle to its diameter.
\end{defi}
%
%\renewcommand{\listtheoremname}{List of Theorems}
%\listoftheorems[ignoreall,show=theorem]
\section*{\listtheoremname}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\listtheoremname}
\listtheorems{theorem,defi}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer... As I commented, my ultimate goal is to put a background color. So I would like the other things to be exactly the same as the default theorem environment. So do you think `theoremframepreskip`, `theoremframepostskip`, `theoreminframepreskip`, `theoreminframepostskip`, etc. should be `6pt` or `4pt`?

Comment: I'm unsure of what what `thmtools` does exactly with `ntheorem`. I know they cooperate. I think it's up to you to choose the values you want, after testing with a viewer that lets make some measurements in the resulting .pdf (SumatraPDF let you do that). I can say  the value of 6pt, in my code (`theoremframepre` and `postskip`), is added to the normal lineskip between the line above an the top of the shaded region (and similarly at the bottom). As to the `\theoreminframepre` and `postskip`, they're the vertical padding above (resp. below) the first (resp. last) line of the shaded environment.