# How to split a theorem using the `shaded' option in thmtools

Tags: amsmath, page-breaking, thmtools

I am using amsmath, thmtools and the following definition to get nice Theorem statements inside a light blue box:

```
\declaretheoremstyle[
  shaded={bgcolor=blue!10},
  numberwithin=section
]{mythmstyle}
\declaretheorem[style=mythmstyle]{theorem}
```

My problem is that these boxes containing theorem statements do not split between pages. Since I tend to use long statements, this produces big unbreakable blocks and the formatting of pages is terrible.

To clarify: I want to modify my settings so that page formatting can split Theorems between pages, which it seems unable to do at the moment. How can I do?

If I remove the `shaded' option, breaking returns to normal, so that should be the culprit

EDIT: a solution is to use the `framed` package. Using amsthm, I define a pre-theorem environment, to get counters right

```
\newtheorem{pretheorem}{Theorem}[section]
```

and then the true theorem environment is defined by inserting a frame as follows:

```
\newenvironment{theorem}
   {\colorlet{shadecolor}{blue!15}
   \begin{snugshade}\begin{pretheorem}}
   {\end{pretheorem}\end{snugshade}}
```

Not too elegant but it seems to work.

Comment: You woud have no problem with the `ntheorem` packaged which enables you to define framed, shaded and boxed theorems that can break across pages. This package requires the `framed` package and cooperates with `thmtools`. Have a look at § 237, "Framed and Boxed Theorems", pp. 9-10 in the documentation.

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately, ```ntheorem``` conflicts with ```amsbook``` which I am using

Answer (score 2):

Can you switch to `tcolorbox` instead of `thmtools`?

```tex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{breakable,theorems}

\newtcbtheorem[number within=section]{mytheorem}{Theorem}{breakable,colback=teal!20,colframe=blue,fonttitle=\bfseries}{thm}

\begin{document}
    \begin{mytheorem}{A theorem}{label}
        \blindtext[5]
    \end{mytheorem}
    Refer it like this: Theorem \ref{thm:label}.
\end{document}
```

Page 1:

[image]

Page 2:

[image]

Comment: Interesting. But this would force me to change my labeling system, for which I have macros in place etc. I think for me the minimal solution with the framed package is better

Comment: Yes, I had expected that suddenly switching packages would cause a lot of overhead. Did you have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34405/shaded-theorems-thmtools-spanning-pages?rq=1 ?

Comment: No, I looked into older posts but this one did not come up. The solution proposed there seems fine. As for complexity it looks the same as the above hack with ```framed```. Do you see any advantages?

Comment: I agree with you. The first part of the answer looks the same. But the second part explains how to incorporate it within `thmtools`'s commands. I thought it might be what you were looking for. You are the best judge anyway :)